# Acknowldegment and Ordering of Push Notification through Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

Is there a way to track the pending notifications against a tag/registration id in NotificationHub ?

Also, is there any ordering on the push notification send through NotificationHub e.g. lets say I send Command 'A' to device first and then Command 'B' (one after another - almost immediately). How will NotiifcationHub manages this? Will it wait for the acknowledgment of first message or it will just send these two messages one after another to PUSH service providers?

Answer (score 0):

Order is not guaranteed for case you describe. Command B is processed as soon as possible regardless to command A status.